# Run python manage.py runserver in vscode and no any response

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

After open the Vscode in Wiondows and run the command python manage.py runserver in the terminal. There are no any response.

[image]

Please advise it. Many thanks.

Please find below manage.py

```
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'FYP.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: use a debugger to see which code lines are executed

Comment: It doesn't print anything, it just imports a module. The code is functioning fine, its just that the code doesn't do anything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @OuterSoda how so? I don't know much Python, but I see the "if main", and the subsequent import, followed by `execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)`. Michael, what happens if you do a basic main function that only prints "hello world" and then exits? Does that result in output in the terminal?

Answer (score 0):

What is your project structure? Why use `.\` in the command? Keep a simple project structure and use the `python manage.py runserver` command.

[image]

Follow the [official document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-django) to start using Django.

You can also add `print("hello")` to check your code on the ***manage.py*** script to check whether your code is executed.

[image]